# Filtering Clustered Points by JSON attributes using Mapbox-gl-js

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Is there way to filter clustered points using mapbox-gl-js by Filter symbols by toggling a list (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/)?

The goal is to build functionality such as this (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/filtering-marker-clusters/)

Answer (score 6):

The GeoJSON clustering happens at the [source](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#GeoJSONSource) level, so if you want to filter data in the clusters, you will have to filter the GeoJSON itself and then update the source with the filtered data. 
`map.getSource('sourceName').setData(filteredData)`

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2b8v7swq/) demonstrating the functionality

disclaimer: I work at Mapbox

Comment: Molly, thanks a lot for this example. Worked perfectly for my project :-)

Comment: How do you filter the geojson?  Can we see an example of this implmented?  The fiddle does not apply this filter.

Comment: @mollymerp currently having a quite similar issue. Could you take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52359737/data-driven-cluster-colour-with-mapboxgl

Comment: @mollymerp also how would that work in terms of performance if we get millions of points?