# Filtering the Clustered Points by JSON attributes using Mapbox-gl-js

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am working on the project in which I want to filter the GeoJson using their attributes and visualize the marker in cluster form on the map.

I try using the following "[Filtering Clustered Points by JSON attributes using Mapbox-gl-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002142/filtering-clustered-points-by-json-attributes-using-mapbox-gl-js/56089433#56089433)"
solution but unable to understand how to filter GeoJson using their attributes and set filter GeoJson data to map.

I already made an application using Google Maps API, but now I want to develop through Mapbox-gl-js API.

Existing Application Link: http://maps.dicrc.in/BM/

Comment: This might be helpful in your switch: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/google-to-mapbox/

Answer (score 3):

Mapbox The GeoJSON clustering happens at the source level. If you want to filter data in the clusters, you will have to filter the GeoJSON itself based on the attributes BEFORE clustering it. 
You can use tools like [turf/filter](https://github.com/turf-junkyard/turf-filter) to filter the GeoJSON data. For clustering and updating your filtered data, follow the example in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51h8wspo/13/) `map.getSource('sourceName').setData(filteredData)`

disclaimer: I work at Mapbox

Comment: What if the source is referencing a URL to a geojson file — so i don't know the data up front — how would I apply a filter?