# Mapbox issue with filtering layers using array of values

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I am having issues with filtering the conversations layer. It seems to work fine on the routes layer even though it seems like the `route_long_name` properties exists on both layers and when I do a manual filter on the features it filters them just fine. Is this just me not understanding filters on map

```
const filterExpression = filters.routes.length > 0 ? [
      'match',
      ['get', 'route_long_name'],
      routes,
      true,
      false
    ] : undefined;
```

this works on the route layer perfectly, but when i use it on the route layer with a type of

```
Feature<
    MultiLineString,
    {
      tc_agency_id: string;
      route_id: string;
      route_long_name: string;
      shape_id: string;
    }
```

but not on the conversation layer

```
Feature<
    Point,
    {
      tc_agency_id: string;
      route_id: string;
      route_long_name: string;
      stop_id: string;
      stop_name: string;
    }
  >[];
```

the WEIRD part is that it works fine when i manually filter the the features

```
console.log({ 
  conversationsource: source._data.features.filter(item => routes.includes(item.properties.route_long_name)), 
  routesource: routesource._data.features.filter(item => routes.includes(item.properties.route_long_name)) 
})}
```

full snippet

```
const routes = filters.routes.map(el => el.routeLongName);
    const filterExpression = filters.routes.length > 0 ? [
      'match',
      ['get', 'route_long_name'],
      routes,
      true,
      false
    ] : undefined;
    const source = mapbox.map.getSource(MapSources.conversationsSource)
    const routesource = mapbox.map.getSource(MapSources.routesSource)
    if (source && routesource) {
      console.log({ 
  source: source._data.features.filter(item => 
    routes.includes(item.properties.route_long_name)), 
  routesource: routesource._data.features.filter(item => 
    routes.includes(item.properties.route_long_name)) })
}
    for (const layerId of [MapLayers.routesLayer, MapLayers.conversationsLayer]) {
      if (mapbox.map.getLayer(layerId)) {
        mapbox.map.setFilter(layerId, filterExpression)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing some digging and it turns out that clustering works at the source level and not the layer level.

[Filtering Clustered Points by JSON attributes using Mapbox-gl-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002142/filtering-clustered-points-by-json-attributes-using-mapbox-gl-js)

So the items were there, but the zoom level was too high to see the areas where filters worked. In order to fix this i will need to get the source and set the data like this.

```
const source = map.getSource(layerId)
const sourceData = mapState[layerId].filter(feat => filterFeature(feat))
source.setData(sourceData)
```